# Haskell parsec: `many` combinator inside an `optional` combinator

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'd like to implement this grammar rule using Haskell's parsec library:

```
((a | b | c)* (a | b))?
```

Which is a parser rule that accepts an optional (i.e. potentially empty) string. If the string it acccepts is not empty, then it can be consumed by passing through zero or more occurrences of the `a` `b` or `c` parsers, but the accepted string by the outer most `?` optional parser *must* be consumed either by parser `a` or `b`, but not `c`. Here's an example:

```haskell
module Main where

import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Text

a,b,c :: GenParser () Char
a = char 'a'
b = char 'b'
c = char 'c'

-- ((a | b | c)* (a | b))?
myParser = undefined

shouldParse1,shouldParse2,shouldParse3,
      shouldParse4,shouldFail :: Either ParseError String
-- these should succeed
shouldParse1 = runParser myParser () "" "" -- because ? optional
shouldParse2 = runParser myParser () ""  "b"
shouldParse3 = runParser myParser () "" "ccccccb"
shouldParse4 = runParser myParser () "" "aabccab"

-- this should fail because it ends with a 'c'
shouldFail = runParser myParser () "" "aabccac"

main = do
  print shouldParse1
  print shouldParse2
  print shouldParse3
  print shouldParse4
  print shouldFail
```

A first attempt might look like this:

```haskell
myParser = option "" $ do
  str <- many (a <|> b <|> c)
  ch  <- a <|> b
  return (str ++ [ch])
```

But the `many` just consumes all 'a' 'b' and 'c' characters in each test case, leaving `a <|> b` no characters to consume.

**The question**:

Using parsec combinators, what is the correct implementation of `((a | b | c)* (a | b))?` to define `myParser`?

Comment: Maybe parse (a|b|c)+ and reject it later if it ends with c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can also state this slightly different: `c` in your parser may only succeed if it's followed by any token, which can be done with a single `lookAhead`:

```
myParser = many (a <|> b <|> (c <* (lookAhead anyToken <?> "non C token"))) <* eof
```

Comment: thanks, that works. I was half expecting it not work because of `anyToken` I had assumed to mean just that, whether that be a 'd', '\n', or whatever. I was thinking something like `myParser = many (a <|> b <|> (c <* (lookAhead (try a <|> try b) <?> "non C token"))) <* eof`. However, your definition of `myParser` *does* work. E.g. Parsing "ca" returns "ca", whereas trying to parse "cd" fails with "unexpected 'd'. expecting "a", "b", "c" or end of input". Why is it the `anyToken` combinator only willing to accept 'a', 'b', or 'c'?

Comment: @RobStewart: Due to `<* eof`. `myParser` expects to consume all input.